# Joomla 3 check if text is written by registered user then hide

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

I develop a Moset tree Website with free and paid Accounts. The author User group can edit more fields then registered User Group. After one year, when the subscription expired the User group changes from author to registered group.

The listing has to stay online, but without the paid fields.

What I Need is a php code to add to the listing template that checks if the owner of the listing is in the registered User Group or in the author User Group. If the user is in the author Group, the Field is displayed, if the owner of the listing in in the registered User group, the field is hidden.

Is that possible?

Comment: Override the template and check the necessary condition in that. You have to go with template overriding documentation and method (JUserHelper::getUserGroups).

Answer (score 0):

You have to locate field display code and add a check using joomla user object.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if(in_array('1', $user->groups)) { // check for group with id: 1
  echo 'display field';
}
```

Reference: [Accessing the current user object](https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object)